# Highcharts column chart histogram show x range in tooltip

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am using the highcharts column chart to create a histogram. (I can't use the histogram chart type because I am using pre-aggregated data). How do I configure the tooltip for the columns to show the date range for the column instead of the start date?

http://jsfiddle.net/3q6gxjph/8/

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    type: 'column'
  },
  xAxis: {
    type: 'datetime'
  },
  yAxis: {
    title: {
      text: 'Count'
    }
  },
  tooltip: {
    headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:10px">{point.key}</span><table>',
    pointFormat: '<tr><td style="color:{series.color};padding:0">{series.name}: </td>' +
      '<td style="padding:0"><b>{point.y}</b></td></tr>',
    footerFormat: '</table>',
    shared: true,
    useHTML: true
  },
  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      pointInterval: 24 * 3600000, // one day
      pointStart: 0,
      pointPlacement: 'between'
    },
    column: {
      groupPadding: 0,
      pointPadding: 0
    }
  },
  series: [{
    data: [49, 71, 106, 129, 144, 176, 135, 148, 216, 194, 95, 54]

  }]
});
```

Comment: You can use tooltip formatter: http://jsfiddle.net/3a6m49aj/

Comment: @morganfree Thanks! It's a bit unfortunate that you have to calculate the end date in the formatter, but this is a working solution (and maybe the best possible). Post it as an answer with code and I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use use [tooltip.formatter](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.formatter) to calculate the range for the point to be visible in the tooltip.

```
tooltip: {
  formatter () {
    const x1 = Highcharts.dateFormat('%Y-%m-%d', this.x)
    const x2 = Highcharts.dateFormat('%Y-%m-%d', this.x + 24 * 3600 * 1000)
    const header = `<span style="font-size:10px">${x1} - ${x2}</span><table>`

    const body = `<tr>
      <td style="color:${this.series.color};padding:0">${this.series.name}: </td>
      <td style="padding:0"><b>${this.y}</b></td>
    </tr>`

    const footer = '</table>'

    return header + body + footer
  },
```

live example: http://jsfiddle.net/3a6m49aj/